# Java CodingErrorAction Report

Tags: java, encoding

I'm currently writing a function which tries to guess the encoding of a textfile.
I came across a part in the Java Documentation that confused me:

> static CodingErrorAction REPORT
>
> Action indicating that a coding error is to be reported, either by returning a CoderResult object or by throwing a CharacterCodingException, whichever is appropriate for the method implementing the coding process

I want that part of my code to throw an exception:

```
CharsetDecoder cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
cs.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
```

But I can't find out how it is decided whether to throw an exception or to return the CoderResult object.

Does anyone know what that documentation means?